# StackOverflowError when saving entity instance using JpaRepository within a job but not in REST API service

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-scheduled

I am experiencing a StackOverflowError when saving an entity instance using the `save` method of `JpaRepository` within a job. However, this only occurs with some instances and not all. The same process of saving the instance works correctly when invoked through a REST API service. In both cases, the instance is retrieved from the database using the `findById` method of `JpaRepository` before being saved. I suspect that the error may be due to multiple Hibernate queries to confirm that the instance to be updated is correct along with its relationships. However, it is unclear why the error occurs in the job and not in the service.

I have provided a stack trace which shows that the error is occurring in the MySQL dialect of Hibernate:
https://pastebin.com/eVFVLMM5

But there is no difference in the Hibernate configuration between the job and the REST API service. I am not using any specific features of Hibernate or handling transactions manually as `JpaRepository` already annotates its data-modifying methods with `@Transactional`. I am processing the same database record in both cases and am using the same methods to retrieve and save data.

I have a class where I configure two jobs (only one of them has this problem), annotated with

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
@Profile(SpringProfiles.X)
@EnableSchedulerLock(defaultLockAtMostFor = "PT1H")
```

For each job, there are two methods: schedule and runner.
The schedule method is annotated with

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelayString = "", initialDelayString = "")
@SchedulerLock(name = "X", lockAtMostFor =)
```

*note that I removed the values of the attributtes for confidencial purposes*
While the runner method is annotated with `@Async`.
The schedule method is responsible for invoking the runner method, and the runner method constructs an object of the Job type and calls its run method.

The job is annotated with the netx anottations:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Component
@Profile(SpringProfiles.X)
```

On the other hand, my main application class is annotated with:

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages="test.package", exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@EnableSwagger2
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableJpaAuditing
@EnableCaching
@Import({BeanValidatorPluginsConfiguration.class, ManagerIntegrationModuleApplication.class}).
```

I am aware that using an custom update instead of the `save` method from `JpaRepository` could work as a solution but right now I am looking to find what exactly the problem is as it may appear in other parts of my application.

I already tried to call a service from the job but the same error appears then that makes me think that there is some difference between the job execution and the service but I cannot figure out what

Comment: Please remove the link to the error stacktrace and paste it as formatted code instead. Please also share the code of entity, service and repository classes where the error occurs.

Comment: Cant share the whole stacktrace as it does not fit in the body. That it is why is in another place

Comment: I do not think that code is necessary for what I am asking cause the entity relationships are not the matter of the problem as  the same algorithm(retrieve and in the next line save) works in a service and not in the job. And what I am doing in the service is exactly what I wrote `findById` the instance and then `save`, both methods from `JpaRepostory`. I hava only those two lines of code inside the job and the service right now for testing purposes trying to find this problem. 
Repository does not have any other than custom methods that I cannot share but are not used in the job and service.